# cant force the edittext width to span along the screen

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

in the below layout file, i created a scrollView and it encompasses a tableLayout. the first row in the tablelayout is an Edittext. and despite i set the Edittext view parameters
to be as follows:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

it never spans along the screen from the left to right!!

please let me know how to make the Edittext spans along the screen from left to right?

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- scrollView can host only one direct parent-->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_label_x1"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_label_x1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="x1: "/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_x1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_label_x1"
                    android:text="x1value" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I should have wrapped the Edittext view inside a Relativelayout for an example, as follows:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_et"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

but I still do not know why it does not work without wrapping the Edittext inside a host layout??!!

Answer (score 0):

`stretchColumns` attribute of `TableLayout` may help.
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- scrollView can host only one direct parent-->
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:stretchColumns="0">

            <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tr0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tr1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rl_label_x1"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_label_x1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="x1: "/>
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_x1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv_label_x1"
                            android:text="x1value"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Strangely it works for my enviroment (emulator, Android 6)

Comment: maybe because in the original layout which is the one i have, there are extra three tablerows beneath the Edittext view. they are somthing like the follwoing:   x1:x1value      x2:x2value      x3:x3value